# Where does language translation fit in the MVC pattern?

Tags: model-view-controller, web-applications, architecture

I'm building a multi-lingual web application using the MVC pattern as the starting position.  The application has a number of forms that users will be interacting with and many of these forms will have fields that do a lookup from a database table, 'Province' for example.

If I need the options in these lists to be displayed in the users' language on the screen, I can see a couple of ways to do this:

1. **In the model.**  When querying the model, I can provide the language that I desire the results to be returned in.  This would allow translations to be used everywhere that data from the model is displayed without changes.  However, this also means that the Province model in my example (plus all other application models) now need to know how to do language translations.
2. **In the controller.**  I can query the model in the controller action as usual and then create a 'Translator' object that I can pass the results into before completing the action.  This would imply that each controller action would potentially be duplicating the same translation code, violating the DRY principle.
3. **In the view.** Since the presentation of the application is generally expected to exist in the views, and the language of the user doesn't impact the business logic of the system, an argument could be made that language translations belong here.  Especially considering that a page could also contain static content that will need to be translated.  The downside to this is that it would complicate the views somewhat, especially for the front-end designers who will have to work around the new translation code.

Is there an accepted best-practice for where text translations belong in the MCV pattern for web applications?  Does this change at all if I were to be loading the select list options via an AJAX call instead of at page load time?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to translate part of your UI, then I would create a helper method that would read a resource file and output a translated string for that resources. E.g.

```
@Translate("NewUserHeading")
```

So regarding the UI, it makes sense to handle this in the UI.

If the data that you are going to translate at some point might be shown in a Flash client, or a mobile app, then it should be translated by a server and it should have nothing to do with your MVC application.

Answer (score 5):

The best place to handle it is in the view. Your question only references dynamic data from the database, but you also have to handle the static information in your views as well. Best to handle both of those in the same place.  A common practice in MVC for handling multiple language is resource strings, separate views for each language, or a combination of both. For information from the database resource strings would work well. You would store a token in the database for the  options in the list (that token could be the English translation) and the view would get the appropriate translation from a resource for the specified country/locale. There is a good detailed explanation on this approach in [this blog post](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, any interaction with a database should be handled in the model, and that's the only thing handled in the model. Interpreting/organizing that data should be handled in the controller. I guess more information would be need as to where this translation is coming from and how that works to really give a solid answer.

Comment: I suppose this would open up the debate between fat models/skinny controllers and skinny models/fat controllers.  I'm I right that you would have your business logic in the controllers?

Comment: @WallyLawless Never heard anybody argue for fat controllers. Controllers are a thin layer translating from view to model and model to view. Controllers are not usually reused, they are just glue, don't fill your code with glue.

Answer (score 0):

The view will just display strings from a resource file. Including the correct resource file for the locale should do it. In Web applications, it's often a single language JS file defining the UI strings per locale, e.g, strings.en-us.js, strings.pt-br.js and so on.

Some strings do come from the server dynamically, the controller doesn't need to know about it, the model should just grab the localized strings and return is as part of the data request.

So it's either in the view (if it's static) or in the model, (if it's dynamic). Controllers should just translate data from the view to the model and from the model to the view

Answer (score 0):

Another very important thing to consider is WHEN to Translate.  Using a **once-per-each-translation** method like `@Translate("NewUserHeading")` is fine if you only have 100 translations on your page, but what if you have more?

Because think about it, translation is based upon *language choice* and that only happens **once-per-page** or even **once-per-session**. The way that the Kendo UI people do it in their demo is that way, when the User clicks a new language a new set of server files is loaded.  That would mean having something like:
/src/html/en-us/
/src/js/en-us/
/src/html/es/
/src/js/es/
etc..

Check it out at https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/localization

It's a trade off of more work for better performance.  The ultimate use-case of translation right now is https://www.jw.org/ with over 900 languages!